# How to use BackgroundWorker rather then Application.DoEvent to prevent application from hanging

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker, doevents

I am beginner in c#/.net, so please tell me how to use BackgroundWorker rather then Application.DoEvent.

This is my code:

```
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState!= WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
  Application.DoEvents(); //how to use "BackgroundWorker" here 
  if (webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
  {                            
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

    var num = listBox1.Items.Count;
    string str = Convert.ToString(num);
    label2.Text = str;                            
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need BackgroundWorker. Just use `DocumentCompleted` event.

```
 webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;


void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     //Do your work   
}
```

Comment: will you please implement "backgroundworker" in my code because i a not getting how to implement this. i want to implement it in "button_click1"

Comment: What do you mean by `will you please implement "backgroundworker"`? What do you want to do in `button_click1`? BackgroundWorker is a mean not the goal.